# VM transaction failed reverting the transaction

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

Solidity smart contract code is:

```
function recharge() public payable {
    address payable _wallet=address(this);
    _wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

javascript code is:

```
this.state.contract.methods.recharge().send({from:this.state.owner,value: Web3.utils.toWei(this.state.Recharge, 'ether')})
```

*contract and owner are stored in a state variable,
but this gives an error
Err0r:VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to send Ether to the contract, there is no need to explicitly send the Ether to `address(this)`. Using an empty function will work:

```
function recharge() public payable {
  // noop
}
```

You can also use a `receive` function to make your contract always accept Ether transactions, without calling the function:

```
receive () external payable {
  // noop
}
```

Comment: Now how do I call recharge() function in web3

Comment: In the same way as you were doing it before, you only need to change the Solidity implementation.